# Attributes in SwiftLint custom regex-based rules

Tags: regex, swiftlint

I am creating custom rule for [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) that checks the spelling of `color`. I need this to be case insensitive.

I am currently matching using `regex: "([C|c]olour)"` but I would like to use the case insensitive modifier `/i`. I have tried the following rule but it doesn't work:

```
custom_rules:
  color_us_english:
    regex: "(colour)/i"
    message: "Use US English spelling to match Apple's API."
    severity: warning
```

How do you use modifiers in SwiftLint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the following is not supported:

```
"(colour)/i"
```

Please try:

```
"(?i)(colour)"
```

Have a look at this [example](https://github.com/Twigz/Game/blob/5a66df769bd2d9e1734857a43abc586887fb8bdc/Dark%20Days/.swiftlint.yml#L41).